# How to access V'dibarta Bam

Tags: support, chat, android-app

How do I access the mi yodeya chat 'V'dibarta Bam'? I'm using the stack exchange android app.

Comment: That's a good question.  I see no way to get to chat from within the app.  (On an Android device you can use the mobile web site or the ChatSEy app, but the Stack Exchange app doesn't seem to have it -- or if it does, it's hidden.)